# Record with Multple Lines Cell Breaks into Multiple Records

Tags: hive, tableau-api, dbeaver

A table is stored in hive with records containing multiple lines cell e.g. `foo\nbar\nbaz` for column C.  The record count of the hive table is perfectly correct, however sometimes in DBeaver and Tableau, the record breaks into 3 records with column C as `foo`, `bar`, `baz` and other columns as null on `bar` and `baz` rows.  Is there a way to fix this issue?  Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to use some other delimiter instead of `\n`?  Some tools and even SerDe (JSONSerDe) interpret \n and \r as  newline and carriage return

Comment: I have been thinking turning them to a list.  But it would damage the readability of those free text.

Comment: Just use some other delimiter if you prefer strings. semicolon, pipe, ^, etc. Everything is good except your current csv columns delimiter (if you are using CSV), TAB, \n, \r, newline and carriage return.